Facing an issue while patching 'Arrival Time' column in PowerApps using Dataverse
I am trying to patch a column 'Arrival Time', I have a custom dropdown I have created for noting down Arrival Time.
Whole form is a custom form.
I have referenced this article for creating both dropdowns for hours and minutes.
https://www.spguides.com/date-time-picker-in-powerapps/
My Patch formula is as follow
Patch(
    Visitors,
    Defaults(Visitors),
    {'REQ ID': 
TextInput2.Text},
    {'VISITOR NAME': 
TextInput2_1.Text},
    {'VISITOR MOBILE NO': Value(
TextInput2_2.Text)},
    {'VISITOR COMPANY NAME': 
TextInput2_3.Text},
    {'PERSON TO MEET': 
ComboBox3.Selected.DisplayName},
    {'VISIT TYPE': 
ComboBox1
.Selected.Value},
    {'VISIT DATE': 
DatePicker1
.SelectedDate},
    {'VISITOR STATUS': 
ComboBox1_1
.Selected.Value},
    {'REQ DATE': DateValue("12/01/2024")},
    {
        'ARRIVAL TIME': Time(
            Value(
Dropdown1
.Selected.Value),
            Value(
Dropdown1_1
.Selected.Value),
            0
        )
    }
)

The 'Arrival Time' column is a DateTime column , I have also tried this
DateValue(Text(Today(),"dd mmm yyyy")) + Time(
Value(
Dropdown1.Selected.Value),
Value(
Dropdown1_1.Selected.Value),
0
)
and its not working , need help , I have been stuck on this for 2 days now

Can you share the error message which you are facing?
